# How to access AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment variables

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to access AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment variables with Flask application.

I setup configuration using AWS GUI
[image: Configuration]

Then load config into environment

According AWS documentation I should be able to access it with `os.environ['KEY']`, but it gives `Internal Server Error, KeyError: 'KEY'`

If I use `os.environ.get('KEY')` the value is None

application.py

```
from flask import Flask
import os

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def index():
    value = os.environ.get('KEY')
    return ("<h1>Hey there, %s</h1>" % value)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug=True)
```

How can access Elastic Beanstalk environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting environment variables here, you are setting resource tags. Tags are helpful for querying your AWS environment for sets of resources. For your purposes, you need to look at setting [Elastic Beanstalk Environment Properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new to AWS and thought that that's how Amazon calls environment variables. Everything worked when I set up them in environment configuration. What left me wondering what tags is used for?

Comment: Tags can be used in billing reports to see how much a specific set of resources is costing you, or to simply query for a specific set of resources in your AWS account. Imagine you had 100 different applications deployed to your AWS account and you needed to find the EC2 servers that were used by one specific application, you would use tags for that.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now. Thanks again for help.